# How to set elevation for flutter page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add flutter in my existing android app(`minSdkVersion 16`) but I am facing elevation problem you can check In these images

before loading flutter view

[image]

**After loading the flutter view**

[image]

**Solution**

Hi problem is get solved by using render mode while creating flutter fragment we just have to give render-mode texture instead of surface like this

```
FlutterFragment flutterFragment = FlutterFragment.withNewEngine()
.renderMode(FlutterView.RenderMode.texture)
.build();
```

Comment: Have you done anything to elevate?

Comment: no I just create a new project and new flutter module and did some ui related change in flutter but not anything related to elevation

Comment: @VirendraVarma Add some code pls

Comment: There is an `elevation` property in `Flutter` use it.

Comment: there is no elevation for `Scaffold`

Comment: Where exactly do you want the elevation to appear? We need to see some code to help you. Please follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't want any elevation and as I said everything here is default code generated by android studio I jjust removed extra code

Comment: thanks every one for your valuable suggestions the problem is get solved by  `renderMode(FlutterView.RenderMode.texture)`